# Asking several questions at once to Quora

Tags: quora

I'm looking for a program, user script, browser plugin, web-service, or anything else that would allow me to ask several questions at once on Quora. Any OS, any license, any price is fine. CLI or GUI. Ideally, a free Python library. I am aware that Quora has no official API to do so.

Comment: "at once": do you mean "one after the other very fast" or it must really be in parallel?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul just from a user standpoint: e.g. you click "ask those 10 questions", and it will post it for you (parallel or sequential, both are fine).

Comment: OK, I have to ask: what's the use case here? I just can't figure out what this is for...

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct out-of-box software, since it affect only small amount of users.

However this should be fairly easy to perform by the following methods:

- [Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) extension for Firefox/Chrome with simple JS script (check for [some examples](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Auserscripts-mirror.org%20quora)),
- [Postman app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) for Chrome where you can save specific sent requests, so you can replay new requests quickly,
- record or write action in [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) plugin for Firefox, then replay.

Since you mention Python (Java or PHP also would work), you can use Selenium plus web driver (e.g. Chrome, PhantomJS), so you can simulate user journey. Here is sample unit test which goes to `http://example.com` then check if `Example` is present on the website:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.base_url = "http://example.com"

    def is_text_present(self, text):
        return str(text) in self.driver.page_source

    def test_example(self):
        self.driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        self.assertTrue(self.is_text_present("Example"))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(FooTest)
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

So you can implement user journey which reads questions from the list of files and for each it'll submit the form using your session cookie.

For simple solution, probably `curl` command would work as well. See: [What is the cURL command-line syntax to do a POST request?](https://superuser.com/q/149329/87805) at SO